# Display integer in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, int, jtextarea

I have created a JTextArea as follows:

```
 JTextArea area = new JTextArea(20,15);
 add(new JScrollPane(area), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I want to it to display the integer "0" when the code runs. I dont know how to add an int to the Area. I have tried the following code for that :

```
   int a= 0;
   area.add(a);
```

BUT THIS DOES NOT WORK.

Comment: But later on I would have to increment the value "0", so I need to initialize an int variable.
@Reimeus

Comment: _I have created a JTextField_ No, you haven't. You have created a `JTextArea`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
area.setText(String.valueOf(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JTextArea area = new JTextArea(...);
area.append("" + 0);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.